# Bit.ly doesn't support OpenId, what URL shortener does?

Tags: url-shortening, bit.ly

Question inspired by this tweet:

> bit.ly still doesn't support OpenID?
>   Any recommendations on a url shortener
>   that does?
>   http://twitter.com/jongalloway/status/17967007628

Comment: what is this good for?

Comment: How does OpenID even matter here? It'll only change how you login.

Comment: One less password and Id to remember-- is there something good about having to remember one more password and user id?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this one http://twurl.cc/ I am not sure how it works but I do know they accept only openIDs for logging into their system.

Here is a list of what were the top 15 URL shorteners as of Jan 20th of this year, http://www.gadgetcage.com/2010/01/top-15-url-shortening-services-to.html